# How to add increment column that add +1 for each new object in a csv for a specific ID

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file containing information with of medication (name), and dose for some patients (id) take.

The CSV file is structured as follows:

```
name, id, dose
ator, 034, 20
ator, 034, 30
para, 034, 30
mar, 035, 20
mar, 034, 10
```

The goal is to parse it into a "long" format, with following columns: "id," "table" (a table name given in the code), field (i.e., name, dose), value (i.e., the value of for instance name or dose). So far I have succeeded in formatting the original CSV structure into this.

But, I also want a column, "count," that contains the increment of medications each patient take.
For instance patient with id 034, takes three medications (ator, para, and mar), corresponding to a count of 1, 2, and 3. Thus, the desired output is the following:

```
id,table,field,count,value
034, meds, name, 1, ator
034, meds, name, 1, ator
034, meds, name, 2, para
035, meds, name, 1, mar
034, meds, name, 3, mar
034, meds, dose, 1, 20
034, meds, dose, 1, 30
034, meds, dose, 2, 30
035, meds, dose, 1, 20
034, meds, dose, 3, 10
```

Every time a patient (i.e., id) gets a new medication (i.e., name) the "count" should represent which medication that corresponds with for instance dose later in the table.

But I am struggling with getting a count column like that.

I have tried to add a count column to the data frame via my code (please, see below) without luck.

Any help for creating this column would be great!

```
import pandas as pd

# load the data into a pandas table:
file = '~/data/meds.csv'                   
df = pd.read_table(file, delimiter=',')

#### CANNOT GET THIS PART TO WORK: #####

count = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    count.append(df[(df['id'] == row['id']) & (df['name'] < row['name'])].shape[0])

df['count'] = count

########################################

# convert data frame into the long format
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['id', 'count'], var_name='field', value_name='value')

# Change all NaNs to None 
df = df.where((pd.notnull(df)), None)

# creating new column with table name
table = []
df['table'] = 'meds'

# save to file:
df.to_csv('~/data/meds_out.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: It seems `['study_id', 'recid']` columns are not in input data, can you add it?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I changed the study_id to id for making the code more simple for this purpose. I will correct it in the code snippet.

Comment: Yes, so solution working?

Comment: Sort of, I would like it to count the medications as counts rather than the ids (i.e., a patient can take the same medication multiple times). But I guess this will work also, just not as I imagined :) Thank you.

Comment: hmmm, working on it, give me some time

Comment: You are the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) with [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter column:

```
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars='id', var_name='field', value_name='value')
#if constant value set this way
df['table'] = 'meds'

df['count'] = df.groupby(['id','field']).cumcount() + 1


#change order of columns if necessary
df = df[['id','table','field','count','value']]
print (df)
   id table field  count value
0  34  meds  name      1  ator
1  34  meds  name      2  para
2  35  meds  name      1   mar
3  34  meds  name      3   mar
4  34  meds  dose      1    20
5  34  meds  dose      2    30
6  35  meds  dose      1    20
7  34  meds  dose      3    10
```

EDIT:

```
df['count'] = df.groupby('id')['name'].cumcount() + 1
df['count'] = df.groupby('id')['count'].ffill().astype(int)
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['id','count'], var_name='field', value_name='value')
print (df)
   id  count field value
0  34      1  name  ator
1  34      2  name  ator
2  34      3  name  para
3  35      1  name   mar
4  34      4  name   mar
5  34      1  dose    20
6  34      2  dose    30
7  34      3  dose    30
8  35      1  dose    20
9  34      4  dose    10
```

Comment: Thank you. It is very close, but unfortunately, one patient (id) can take the same medication (name) multiple times. It needs to count the number of different medications rather than count the id. For instance, ator is counted as 1 for id 034, the second time 034 takes ator, it should count as 1 again. Then 034 takes para, and it counts as 2. I hope I make sense :)